# Popup bar in Mail application

Tags: android

In the Android Mail application, when you click the checkbox next to an inbox message, a little bar with buttons (mark unread, delete, star) appears at the bottom of the screen.  I'd like to do something similar, but I don't think I'm going about it the right way.

What I've done is add a LinearLayout below my ListView and marked the visibility GONE.  When a user clicks a checkbox next to a list item, the LinearLayout's visibility is marked VISIBLE.  Unfortunately, checkboxes stop working.  By this I mean the skin on the checkbox does not change from unchecked to checked; and I can't figure out why.

(...or rather, this is the way I HAD it. I removed it once I couldn't fix it and, since trying to add it again, it just crashes, but I digress)

What is the best way to architect what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=tree) of the AndroidMail app that you're referring to. I was able to re-use the CursorAdapter included in MessageList.java with very little modification for one of my apps.

Comment: It looks like they're doing the same thing I am, with some animation added.  Though I still have my original problem.  When I click the checkbox, the checkbox does not re-skin to the checked state.  If I click it again (after my popup is now showing), it will check.  I wonder if showing the popup messes with indexes in a weird way?